# A criterion for surjectiveness in a complete metric space

Tags: metric-spaces

I was facing the following problem:
**Let X be  a compact metric space. Let f: X to X be a function, such that d(f(x),f(y))=d(x,y) for all x,y in X. Show that f is surjective.**
Can I somehow use the fixed point theorem in complete metric spaces to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: If $f$ is not surjective, let $x_0\in X\setminus f[X]$. For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$. Now consider the sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$.